# Retrieving values of one level of a MultiIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex

```
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A', 0), ('A', 1), ('B', 1), ('B', 2)], names=['Letters', 'Numbers'])
```

which loos like that

```
Letters  Numbers
A        0
A        1
B        1
B        2
```

How can I retrieve all values of the second level, given a value of the first level? That is, given A, I would like to get [0, 1], and given B, I would like to get [1, 2].

The only way that I can think of is

```
ind.get_level_values(1)[ind.get_level_values(0) == 'B']
```

But that does not look very nice and I was hoping that there is a more elegant expression. Is there?

Answer (score 2):

Simpliest and fastest is use list comprehension:

```
a = [x[1] for x in ind.tolist() if x[0] == 'A']
print (a)

[0, 1]
```

Another possible solution is create helper `df` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ind.tolist(), columns=['a','b'])
print (df)
   a  b
0  A  0
1  A  1
2  B  1
3  B  2

a = df.loc[df['a'] == 'A', 'b'].tolist()
print (a)
[0, 1]

a = df.loc[df['a'] == 'B', 'b'].tolist()
print (a)
[1, 2]
```

But in my opinion your solution is nice (a bit changed for select by levels names):

```
a = ind.get_level_values('Numbers')[ind.get_level_values('Letters') == 'B'].tolist()
print (a)
[1, 2]
```

**Timings**:

```
In [197]: %timeit ([x[1] for x in ind.tolist() if x[0] == 'A'])
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.14 µs per loop

In [199]: %timeit ind.get_level_values('Numbers')[ind.get_level_values('Letters') == 'B'].tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 377 µs per loop


In [200]: %%timeit
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(ind.tolist(), columns=['a','b'])
     ...: df.loc[df['a'] == 'A', 'b'].tolist()
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.06 ms per loop
```

Comment: Actually, I was hoping for something that looks like `ind.loc[ind.loc[:, 'Letters'] == 'A', 'Numbers']`, that is, a similar syntax as if those would be columns not index levels. Still thanks for the list comprehension and the timing! I wonder if the speed comparison remains valid for large DataFrames. Why do you actually use tolist()? It is also possible to iterate directly over the index.

Comment: It working only with DataFrame :(. and I add list, but maybe is not necessary. I test it.

Comment: No, not necessary.

Comment: `MultiIndex` in my opinion can be simplify by list of tuples, so very nice working list comprehension. What is size of your real df?

Comment: Say, 100000 rows.

Comment: In my opinion list comprehension will be faster. Hard test it, because now on phone only. Also it depends of size of levels, I think if in 10k in first level is unique values 10 or 1000. The best is test it in your real data.